# Asking 2 new questions on SO

Tags: support, asking-questions

About 7 hours ago I posted a question on SO. Now I went to post another one using the "Ask question" option, but instead of an empty form, I got the form pre-filled with the previous question I asked, as if I were editing it instead of asking a new one.

I have not tried to modify this, as I don't want to accidentally lose my first question in case it is in edit mode.

Is it just my browser or a bug in SO?

Comment: "[Which database for update-heavy application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10705244/which-database-for-update-heavy-application)" is the most recent question I see [from your account](http://stackoverflow.com/users/14690/milan-babuskov?tab=questions&sort=newest), and it's 7 hours old.

Comment: It's been 7 hrs? OMG, time flies :) I fixed the question. Problem still remains.

Comment: This sounds like the autosave feature at work. It should go away when you post the question though.

Comment: Pekka, what does that mean? How do I create a completely new question if it keeps giving me the old one to edit?

Comment: The editor saves a draft of your post as you edit in case you accidentally navigate away, etc. It's probably showing you the old draft content in a new question. Look at the top bar - if there's no question ID in the URL then you're not editing. (And even if you do accidentally trash your old question, edits are easy enough to roll back!)

Comment: Thanks Rup, I completely forgot about reverting edits. Could you please copy/paste your comment as an answer so that I can accept it.